# Observable/toObservable not found as static function?

Tags: java, clojure, reactive-programming, rx-java

Using rxjava (http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/) under lighttable with clojure 1.5.1, consider the following (using a side-effecting, mutating (horrors!) external collector to extract data from the monad)

```
(ns expt1.core (:import [rx]))

(def ^:private collector (atom []))
(defn- collect [item]
  (reset! collector (conj @collector item)))

(def string-explode (partial map identity))

(reset! collector [])
(->
 (Observable/toObservable ["one" "two" "three"])
 (.mapMany #(Observable/toObservable (string-explode %)))
 (.subscribe collect)
 )

@collector
```

which produces:

```
[\o \n \e \t \w \o \t \h \r \e \e]
```

I would like to say

```
(reset! collector [])
(->
 (Observable/toObservable ["one" "two" "three"])
 (.mapMany (comp Observable/toObservable string-explode))
 (.subscribe collect)
 )
```

but, surprise

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: toObservable in class rx.Observable, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:93:1)
             Compiler.java:6380 clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze
             Compiler.java:6322 clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze
             Compiler.java:3624 clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse
             Compiler.java:6562 clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq
             ...
```

in fact, just

```
Observable/toObservable
```

produces a similar exception. Why can Clojure find `Observable/toObservable` when it's in an expression like

```
#(Observable/toObservable (string-explode %))
```

but not in an expression like

```
(comp Observable/toObservable string-explode)
```

?

Comment: If you want to extract the data from the Observable, just use `Observable/toList` and then `rx.observables.BlockingObservable/single`. Or just `rx.observables.BlockingObservable/getIterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Observable/toObservable` is a Java method, not a Clojure function. You can't treat Java methods as function values, like you can do with Clojure functions. `comp` composes Clojure functions (objects that implement the `IFn` interface). Solution: wrap the method call in a Clojure function.

One other thing:

```
(defn- collect [item]
  (reset! collector (conj @collector item)))
```

should be:

```
(defn- collect [item]
  (swap! collector conj item)))
```

Only use `reset!` on an atom when you don't want to use the old value. When you do, use `swap!`, else an atomic update is not guaranteed (another thread could update the atom after you read its value).

Comment: Thanks for the atom tip, too. I definitely missed that one!